# trouble with fread() function in the code

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C to open bitmap image and save the dimension the image. i am having some problem to write the fread() function. please tell me what should be the correct format for the function in the code that i have written.

here i have used pointer array because i have to open multiple bitmap images.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void fskip(FILE *fp, int num_bytes)
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<num_bytes; i++)
      fgetc(fp);
}

typedef struct tagBITMAP              /* The structure for a bitmap. */
{
 int width;
 int height;
 //unsigned char *data;
} BITMAP;


int main()
{
    int temp1=0;
    BITMAP *bmp[50];

    FILE *fp = fopen("splash.bmp","rb");

    if (fp!=NULL && (fgetc(fp)=='B' && fgetc(fp)=='M')){

    bmp[temp1] = (BITMAP *) malloc (sizeof(BITMAP));

    fskip(fp,16);
    fread(&bmp[temp1].width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    fskip(fp,2);
    fread(&bmp[temp1].height,sizeof(int), 1, fp);



     fclose(fp);
     }
     else exit(0);

     getch();

     }
```

Comment: "i am having some problem to write the fread() function."  What do you expect to happen?  What is actually happening?

Comment: Rollback to previous version, don't correct question

Comment: i have corrected the fread() function. but there is a new problem that it is not reading the width correctly. it is displaying width = 65536. i have posted the corrected code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fread(&bmp[temp1].width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

should be:

```
fread(&(bmp[temp1]->width), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

because `bmp[temp1]` is address of struct use `->` operator instead of `.` Same error is in second `fread()`.

`.` DOT that works with value variable called `element selection by reference`.
`->` is used called `element selection through pointer`.

Comment: thenks for the help. i have corrected the fread() function. but there is a new problem that it is not reading the width correctly. it is displaying width = 65536. i have posted the corrected code.

Comment: @user2540082 for that I am not sure, show your input file, add that you wants to read.

Comment: i have tried the code different bitmap images on my system. all are giving the same output. you can try it with any bitmap image on your system.

Comment: @user2540082 I think first mistake is your if condition is wrong! In `(fgetc(fp)=='B' && fgetc(fp)=='M'))` two `fgetc()` will read two different chars.

Comment: @user2540082 Are you sure you wants to read two continue char **?** , I think you should fist read and save char in a tempC variable then use that variable in if-condition

Comment: @user2540082 then next possible points of bug are `fskip(fp,16);`, possible wrong numbers of skips